# Adding pdf or Word attachments to Outlook mail using Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba, email, outlook

I have a working macro to send communications to hundreds of employees.

I personalize the contents using HTML in Excel. The cells contain the messages.

Now, I need to send email with multiple attachments.

Here's the code without the attachments.

```
Sub SendMail()

Dim olApp As Outlook.Application
Dim olMail As Outlook.MailItem

For i = 2 To Sheet1.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

    Set olApp = New Outlook.Application
    Set olMail = olApp.CreateItem(olMailItem)

    With olMail
        .SentOnBehalfOfName = "HC-Communications@company.com"
        .To = Cells(i, 1).Value
        .CC = Cells(i, 2).Value
        .BCC = Cells(i, 3).Value
        .Subject = Cells(i, 4).Value
        .BodyFormat = olFormatHTML
        .HTMLBody = Cells(i, 5).Value
        .Display
        .ReadReceiptRequested = True
        .Send
    End With

    Set olMail = Nothing    
    Set olApp = Nothing

Next

End Sub
```

Comment: `.Attachments.Add`. Here's the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.attachments.add).

Comment: By the way, I inherited the file that I am currently using and made some improvements from the initial file that I got. Will it be possible to get the file from a certain folder in my pc or get the file from the excel file?

Comment: @BigBen, Thanks. Now just get it to send using different files from a folder in my desktop. Is there a way to send a specific file to one person thru vba and the next email will contain a different recipient with a different attachment?

Comment: Sure. How are you distinguishing the different attachments? Is there a file path in your file?

Comment: @ShaunSantos Big Ben knows his stuff. Just do what he says.

Comment: @BigBen, I have them in a folder in my desktop. I have renamed each file to the name of the employee so I can distinguish them. The ideal set up is a macro that can send email to multiple employees with a personalized attachment that he/she should receive. Each employee should receive a different file. At the moment, I can only do multiple emails with the same file (Thanks to BigBen). By the way, I just started learning macro in VBA as this was handed over to me a few weeks ago. Still learning the tricks.

Comment: Ok. So you probably want to use the `Dir` function and the employee name to identify which file should be attached to the email.

Comment: Thanks @BigBen! I'll do some tests using the Dir function. I'll let you if it works. Have a nice day ahead!

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are interested in the [Add](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.attachments.add) method of the `Attachments` class which creates a new attachment in the `Attachments` collection. The source of the attachment can be a file (represented by the full file system path with a file name) or an Outlook item that constitutes the attachment. For example:

```
Sub AddAttachment() 
 Dim myItem As Outlook.MailItem 
 Dim myAttachments As Outlook.Attachments  
 Set myItem = Application.CreateItem(olMailItem) 

 Set myAttachments = myItem.Attachments 
 myAttachments.Add "C:\Test.doc", olByValue, 1, "Test" 

 myItem.Display 
End Sub
```

Comment: still having problems trying to send multiple emails with a different attachments. Cannot figure out how to do it.